# Can vimrc 'tell' if syntax is on or off?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I want to write a simple function that will toggle syntax highlighting, I imagine it'll just be a simple if-else.

Is there a condition I can check?  If "syntax is on"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use global variable `g:syntax_on` (more specifically, the existence of such variable) to determine whether syntax highlighting is on or off.

See [`:help g:syntax_on`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#g%3Asyntax_on), which actually even includes an example of a mapping that toggles syntax highlighting:

```
:map <F7> :if exists("g:syntax_on") <Bar>
    \   syntax off <Bar>
    \ else <Bar>
    \   syntax enable <Bar>
    \ endif <CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can toggle syntax state for each buffer individually,

```
syntax manual
map <F12> <cmd>let &syntax = exists('b:current_syntax') ? 'OFF' : 'ON'<CR>
```